# Personalized marker with personalized icon and html on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, icons, marker

I need to create an personalized marker with custom icon and html strings internal.
A merger between divIcon, Icon and marker function.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/638M6.png)

The image can not be inserted by the css since I will have to call it dynamically.

[My result](http://www.meteocloud.it/rete/livemap.php)

```html
var myIcon = L.divIcon({
 className: 'my-div-icon',
 iconSize: [60, 15],
    iconAnchor: [60, 15],
 html: "<?php echo "<a href='http://www.......' target='_blank'>{$arraydatareadILAZIOCI9[2]} °C</a>"; ?>"});
    L.marker([41.591, 12.831], {
 icon: myIcon,
 }).addTo(temperature);
```

Thank's

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MeteoCloud: should the current answer not solving your above question, you should already be able to _comment_ under that answer to request further explanation. Should you still need help beyond the above question, please open a new question with relevant details. Make sure you read the [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you need an image, just use css like this:

```
.my-div-icon {
    background-color: #fd8424;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #ca6a1b;
}
```

Even if you want have different coloured markers depending on content, you just do something like:

```
.my-div-icon {
    background-color: #fd8424;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #ca6a1b;
}

.my-div-icon.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

then when dynamically creating your markers, add the colour as a class something like:

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'my-div-icon <?php echo $array[$i]['colour'];?>',
    iconSize: [60, 15],
    ...
```